# What is the use of ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the use of ThreadLocal when a Thread normally works on variable keeping it in its local cache ?

Which means thread1 do not know the value of same var in thread2 even if no ThreadLocal is used .

Comment: There is no "local cache" in the Java language.  ("cache" is an implementation detail, not part of the language itself.)  There are local _variables_, which exist only in the _activation records_ of Java methods.  When some thread t calls a method m, an activation record is pushed on the thread's _call stack_.  The activation record holds all of the local variables and arguments for the method, and when the method returns, the activation record is popped off of the stack (i.e. destroyed).  Each thread has its own call stack, so no thread can ever see an activation record belonging to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thread doesn't *have* to keep variables in its local cache -- it's just that it's *allowed* to, unless you tell it otherwise.

So:

- If you want to **force** a thread to share its state with other threads, you have to use synchronization of some sort (including `synchronized` blocks, `volatile` variables, etc).
- If you want to **prevent** a thread from sharing its state with other threads, you have to use `ThreadLocal` (assuming the object that holds the variable is known to multiple threads -- if it's not, then everything is thread-local anyway!).

Comment: Re, _If you want to prevent a thread from sharing its state with other threads, you_ have _to use_ `ThreadLocal`:  That is not true.  There are other, better ways for a thread to keep its own state hidden from other threads.  `ThreadLocal` is for the should-be-rare case where you need a variable whose _scope_ is global, but whose _extent_ is limited to a single thread.  I say "should-be-rare" because global variables should be rare regardless of whether they are thread-local or not.

Comment: @jameslarge That's a good claraification to make explicit -- it's what I meant by the "assuming" clause in the parentheses.

Answer (score 7):

With multiple threads, although you have to do work to make sure you read the "most recent" value of a variable, you expect there to be effectively one variable per instance (assuming we're talking about instance fields here). You might read an out of date value unless you're careful, but basically you've got one variable.

With `ThreadLocal`, you're explicitly *wanting* to have one value per thread that reads the variable. That's typically for the sake of context. For example, a web server with some authentication layer might set a thread-local variable early in request handling so that any code within the execution of that request can access the authentication details, without needing any explicit reference to a context object. So long as all the handling is done on the one thread, and that's the *only* thing that thread does, you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of a global variable for the thread itself, so that any code running in the thread can access it directly. (A "really" global variable can be accessed by any code running in the "process"; we could call it ProcessLocal:)

Is global variable bad? Maybe; it should be avoided if we can. But sometimes we have no choice, we cannot pass the object through method parameters, and ThreadLocal proves to be useful in many designs without causing too much trouble.